# GDB Debug information on scalar storage order

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, endianness, debug-symbols

We have recently started using the GCC scalar_storage_order attribute for C structures which are shared between processors with different endianness.

The "problem" we are trying to solve is that it appears the debugger interprets the structure fields in the processor native scalar order (endianness).

1. Is there a way to include the endianness information for scalars in a structure in the debug information using GCC?
2. Does GDB support different endianness for specific structure definitions?

Please indicate if the question is not clear and thanks for any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting this gcc issue https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82509, which was fixed in yet unreleased gcc 8.0.

As far as I understand you can try to apply the patch to your current gcc and also apply attached patch to gdb: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2017-10/msg00266.html to solve the problem you are seeing.